# Install ruby with rbenv ansible

Tags: ruby, rbenv, ansible

I'm trying to bootstrap a rails dev environment with ansible on Ubuntu 14.04, using rbenv to handle managing ruby versions. I have a playbook that does various things that work successfully but I've taken out the relevant parts in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/smcabrera/4463ed05debe34f3eff5)

Upon running this task:

```
- name: Install ruby with rbenv
  sudo_user: "{{ username }}"
  #command: rbenv install {{ ruby_version }}
  command: zsh -lc "rbenv install {{ ruby_version }}"
```

I get the following error

```
failed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["zsh", "-lc", "rbenv install 2.1.2"], "delta": "0:00:00.005791", "end": "2015-04-21 09:31:19.184810", "rc": 127, "start": "2015-04-21 09:31:19.179019"}
stderr: zsh:1: command not found: rbenv
```

All previous tasks are successful, including getting 
For some reason upon running this I get an error that rbenv is not installed.

You can see I commented out just using "rbenv install" because someone suggested that since rbenv counts on your certain things being in your `.bashrc` (or `.zshrc` in my case) you need to run it with the shell. But this didn't work either.

I also tried adding a task to restart my shell using the `raw` module. And I tried running with `shell` instead of `command`.

[Here's my zshrc](https://gist.github.com/smcabrera/4dabfa7b62b471d60ae5) in case that's relevant.

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589745/install-rbenv-using-ansible) but they just mentioned a problem with using "when" with newer version. Also no one answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133850/how-to-install-gems-for-rbenv-using-ansible), which is similar.

Comment: The rbenv binary isn't being found in your PATH. Have you tried sourcing your `~/.bashrc` (or whatever file you're declaring your `rbenv init` in)? Moreover, did you remember to add these lines after installing rbenv https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#basic-github-checkout?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like for some reason the command `zsh -lc` is not properly loading the value of `PATH` to include the `rbenv` command, even though you have it set in your `.zshrc`.

This is a bit of a hack, but I was able to get `rbenv` running by replacing

`command: zsh -lc "rbenv install {{ ruby_version }}"`

with

`command: zsh -lc "{{home_dir}}.rbenv/bin/rbenv install {{ ruby_version }}"`